# How can I fire the Tab keypress when the Enter key is pressed?

Tags: javascript

This is what I have and it works fine.
But I want to return the tab key instead of just nothing happening.

```
$(document).on("keypress", ":input:not(textarea):not([type=submit])", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

What I want is:

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return event.keyCode = 9; <<= or something similar and simple
}
```

This seems like a duplicate but I don't see anything to substitute enter for tab code... Tab key already knows to skip hidden and use tab orders.

Comment: I think by "return the tab key" you mean that you want to fire a second event as if the tab key had been pressed. (You just assume that "returning" is the way to accomplish that.)

Comment: yes to both... It just seemed to me it would be tighter code to substitute if key == 13 and return code 9 instead. I have to prevent default enter so why not tab instead?

Comment: I would recommend against this approach as you're breaking user expectations regarding reasonable browser usability regarding form input and usage of basic web controls. And it will also be non-intuitive for vision impaired users, if that's something that concerns you.

Comment: I second Mano's comment. It's really annoying when developers try to be clever and break common UX expectations.

Comment: @ManoDestra : agreed in general, but this time it's needed to stop the return key from submitting the form. But instead of no action on return why not tab. I have another reason to stop return key submit but not for this discussion.

Comment: @DanielYantis: Totally see how you got there, but in general, the bar for unusual behavior probably needs to be higher than "why not"? :-)

Comment: I love you guys! But what I want is to specifically make the enter key act like a tab key... Is it possible to substitute key code 13 for 9? and since that is what I want to accomplish - rather than coding it all out the suggested way of set focus to next field (which is not all a tab key does) "why not" substitute the key 13 for 9?

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events. I've tried a quick test of it and I can't quite get it working yet. Personally, I think it's an absolutely filthy hack, but knock yourself out :D

Comment: You are correct - that's awful! ok I give up and will just use the accepted way of next().focus()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect what you *really* want is to move to the next field in the form.

If so, you can easily find the next form field and use `.focus()` to focus it. For instance:

```
var fields = $(this).closest("form").find("input, textarea");
var index = fields.index(this) + 1;
fields.eq(
  fields.length <= index
  ? 0
  : index
).focus();
```

Example:

```js
$(document).on("keypress", ":input:not(textarea):not([type=submit])", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var fields = $(this).closest("form").find("input, textarea");
    var index = fields.index(this) + 1;
    fields.eq(
      fields.length <= index
      ? 0
      : index
    ).focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label>
      Field 1:
      <input type="text">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
      Field 2:
      <input type="text">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
      Field 3:
      <input type="text">
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you're using `tabindex` to put fields in a different order than document order, you'll have to do a bit more work, basically sorting the result of `find` on `tabindex` and working from there. But that should get you going the right way.

Comment: This is where the duplicate question would be valid. Yes this will work and even do what I want. But the question remains: can I substitute the return key code for the tab key code?

Comment: @DanielYantis: Sorry, completely failed to answer *that* question, didn't I? :-) I don't *think* you can. You could try to create a synthetic `KeyboardEvent`, but I doubt the results would be good, cross-browser, especially as the area around synthetic built-in events has been a real moving target... But maybe the latest makes it possible, I may be slightly out of date as I never find I need to synthesize built-in events.

Answer (score 1):

I got the accepted answer to work for me, but I needed to figure out where to stick the code exactly:

```
$(document).on("keypress", ":input:not(textarea):not([type=submit])", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var fields = $(this).closest("form").find("input, textarea");
        var index = fields.index(this) + 1;

        fields.eq(
            fields.length <= index
                ? 0
                : index
        ).focus();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```